# Possible Mistake in Carothers' "Real Analysis"

Tags: real-analysis

Right after example 1.6 in the first chapter, Carothers asserts that the nested interval property implies the least upper bound property and provides this proof:

[image]

However, I was taught that the nested interval property alone is not sufficient, and that one needs the Archimedean property alongside it to prove LUB. So, which one is it  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. You need the archimedian property. His proof implicitely uses this when he writes that $\mathrm{length(I_1)}/2^{n-1} \to 0$ when $n\to \infty$.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you! Carothers should've been more clear.